# Identical tuples give different pickles

Tags: python

The situation is pretty strange and I expect that there is something that I don't know about the pickle module.

I have two tuples `s1` and `s2`. If I compare them it returns `True`.

```
s1 == s2
True
```

If I pickle them and compare results, it returns `False`

```
pickle.dumps(s1) == pickle.dumps(s2)
False
```

Let's look on these byte strings. They are really different:

```
pk1 = pickle.dumps(s1)
pk2 = pickle.dumps(s2)

print(pk1)
b'\x80\x03((X!\x00\x00\x00AA1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0N0P4P4a2a3q\x00X!\x00\x00\x00AA1A3A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0N1P3P4a2a3q\x01K\x01\x86q\x02X!\x00\x00\x00AA2A3A4D2D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2q\x03K\x02\x86q\x04X!\x00\x00\x00AA4A5A5D1D2D2D3H2H4H4N5N5P2P2a2a4q\x05K\x05\x86q\x06X!\x00\x00\x00DA1A3A4A4D2D2D2H1H2H3N4N4P2P2a1a3q\x07K\x04\x86q\x08X!\x00\x00\x00DA2A3A3A4D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0P0a1a3q\tK\x04\x86q\nX!\x00\x00\x00DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3q\x0bK\x04\x86q\x0cX!\x00\x00\x00DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3q\rK\x04\x86q\x0eX!\x00\x00\x00HA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2q\x0fK\x02\x86q\x10X!\x00\x00\x00HA1A2A2A4D2D2D3D3H1H2N1N2P2P2a1a2q\x11K\x02\x86q\x12X!\x00\x00\x00HA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H1H2N3N3P1P2a0a2q\x13K\x03\x86q\x14X!\x00\x00\x00NA0A0A2A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0P3P4a2a3q\x15K\x00\x86q\x16X!\x00\x00\x00NA0A1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0P4P4a2a3q\x17K\x00\x86q\x18X!\x00\x00\x00PA2A3A3A4D0D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0a1a3q\x19K\x04\x86q\x1aX!\x00\x00\x00PA2A3A4A4D0D0D0D2H2H2H3N4N4P0a2a3q\x1bK\x04\x86q\x1cX!\x00\x00\x00aA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a2q\x1dK\x02\x86q\x1eX!\x00\x00\x00aA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H0H1H2N3N3P1P2a2q\x1fK\x03\x86q tq!(h\x01h\x00K\x01\x86q"h\x03K\x03\x86q#h\x05K\x05\x86q$h\x07K\x04\x86q%h\tK\x03\x86q&h\x0bK\x04\x86q\'h\rK\x04\x86q(h\x0fK\x02\x86q)h\x11K\x01\x86q*h\x13K\x03\x86q+h\x15K\x00\x86q,h\x17K\x01\x86q-h\x19K\x03\x86q.h\x1bK\x04\x86q/h\x1dK\x02\x86q0h\x1fK\x03\x86q1tq2(h\x03h\x00K\x02\x86q3h\x01K\x03\x86q4h\x05K\x04\x86q5h\x07K\x03\x86q6h\tK\x03\x86q7h\x0bK\x02\x86q8h\rK\x03\x86q9h\x0fK\x00\x86q:h\x11K\x02\x86q;h\x13K\x02\x86q<h\x15K\x02\x86q=h\x17K\x02\x86q>h\x19K\x03\x86q?h\x1bK\x03\x86q@h\x1dK\x00\x86qAh\x1fK\x02\x86qBtqC(h\x05h\x00K\x05\x86qDh\x01K\x05\x86qEh\x03K\x04\x86qFh\x07K\x01\x86qGh\tK\x02\x86qHh\rK\x02\x86qIh\x0bK\x03\x86qJh\x0fK\x04\x86qKh\x11K\x04\x86qLh\x13K\x02\x86qMh\x15K\x05\x86qNh\x17K\x05\x86qOh\x19K\x02\x86qPh\x1bK\x02\x86qQh\x1dK\x04\x86qRh\x1fK\x02\x86qStqT(h\x07h\x00K\x04\x86qUh\x01K\x04\x86qVh\x03K\x03\x86qWh\x05K\x01\x86qXh\tK\x02\x86qYh\x0bK\x02\x86qZh\rK\x02\x86q[h\x0fK\x03\x86q\\h\x11K\x02\x86q]h\x13K\x01\x86q^h\x15K\x04\x86q_h\x17K\x04\x86q`h\x19K\x02\x86qah\x1bK\x02\x86qbh\x1dK\x03\x86qch\x1fK\x01\x86qdtqe(h\th\x00K\x04\x86qfh\x01K\x03\x86qgh\x03K\x03\x86qhh\x05K\x02\x86qih\x07K\x02\x86qjh\x0bK\x01\x86qkh\rK\x01\x86qlh\x0fK\x03\x86qmh\x11K\x02\x86qnh\x13K\x01\x86qoh\x15K\x03\x86qph\x17K\x04\x86qqh\x19K\x00\x86qrh\x1bK\x00\x86qsh\x1dK\x03\x86qth\x1fK\x01\x86qutqv(h\x0bh\x00K\x04\x86qwh\x01K\x04\x86qxh\x03K\x02\x86qyh\x05K\x03\x86qzh\x07K\x02\x86q{h\tK\x01\x86q|h\rK\x01\x86q}h\x0fK\x03\x86q~h\x11K\x03\x86q\x7fh\x13K\x02\x86q\x80h\x15K\x04\x86q\x81h\x17K\x04\x86q\x82h\x19K\x01\x86q\x83h\x1bK\x00\x86q\x84h\x1dK\x03\x86q\x85h\x1fK\x02\x86q\x86tq\x87(h\rh\x00K\x04\x86q\x88h\x01K\x04\x86q\x89h\x03K\x03\x86q\x8ah\x05K\x02\x86q\x8bh\x07K\x02\x86q\x8ch\tK\x01\x86q\x8dh\x0bK\x01\x86q\x8eh\x0fK\x03\x86q\x8fh\x11K\x03\x86q\x90h\x13K\x02\x86q\x91h\x15K\x04\x86q\x92h\x17K\x04\x86q\x93h\x19K\x01\x86q\x94h\x1bK\x00\x86q\x95h\x1dK\x03\x86q\x96h\x1fK\x02\x86q\x97tq\x98(h\x0fh\x00K\x02\x86q\x99h\x01K\x02\x86q\x9ah\x03K\x00\x86q\x9bh\x05K\x04\x86q\x9ch\x07K\x03\x86q\x9dh\tK\x03\x86q\x9eh\x0bK\x03\x86q\x9fh\rK\x03\x86q\xa0h\x11K\x02\x86q\xa1h\x13K\x02\x86q\xa2h\x15K\x02\x86q\xa3h\x17K\x02\x86q\xa4h\x19K\x03\x86q\xa5h\x1bK\x03\x86q\xa6h\x1dK\x00\x86q\xa7h\x1fK\x02\x86q\xa8tq\xa9(h\x11h\x00K\x02\x86q\xaah\x01K\x01\x86q\xabh\x03K\x02\x86q\xach\x05K\x04\x86q\xadh\x07K\x02\x86q\xaeh\tK\x02\x86q\xafh\x0bK\x03\x86q\xb0h\rK\x03\x86q\xb1h\x0fK\x02\x86q\xb2h\x13K\x01\x86q\xb3h\x15K\x01\x86q\xb4h\x17K\x02\x86q\xb5h\x19K\x02\x86q\xb6h\x1bK\x02\x86q\xb7h\x1dK\x02\x86q\xb8h\x1fK\x01\x86q\xb9tq\xba(h\x13h\x00K\x03\x86q\xbbh\x01K\x03\x86q\xbch\x03K\x02\x86q\xbdh\x05K\x02\x86q\xbeh\x07K\x01\x86q\xbfh\tK\x01\x86q\xc0h\x0bK\x02\x86q\xc1h\rK\x02\x86q\xc2h\x0fK\x02\x86q\xc3h\x11K\x01\x86q\xc4h\x15K\x03\x86q\xc5h\x17K\x03\x86q\xc6h\x19K\x01\x86q\xc7h\x1bK\x02\x86q\xc8h\x1dK\x02\x86q\xc9h\x1fK\x00\x86q\xcatq\xcb(h\x15h\x00K\x00\x86q\xcch\x01K\x00\x86q\xcdh\x03K\x02\x86q\xceh\x05K\x05\x86q\xcfh\x07K\x04\x86q\xd0h\tK\x03\x86q\xd1h\x0bK\x04\x86q\xd2h\rK\x04\x86q\xd3h\x0fK\x02\x86q\xd4h\x11K\x01\x86q\xd5h\x13K\x03\x86q\xd6h\x17K\x00\x86q\xd7h\x19K\x03\x86q\xd8h\x1bK\x04\x86q\xd9h\x1dK\x02\x86q\xdah\x1fK\x03\x86q\xdbtq\xdc(h\x17h\x00K\x00\x86q\xddh\x01K\x01\x86q\xdeh\x03K\x02\x86q\xdfh\x05K\x05\x86q\xe0h\x07K\x04\x86q\xe1h\tK\x04\x86q\xe2h\x0bK\x04\x86q\xe3h\rK\x04\x86q\xe4h\x0fK\x02\x86q\xe5h\x11K\x02\x86q\xe6h\x13K\x03\x86q\xe7h\x15K\x00\x86q\xe8h\x19K\x04\x86q\xe9h\x1bK\x04\x86q\xeah\x1dK\x02\x86q\xebh\x1fK\x03\x86q\xectq\xed(h\x19h\x00K\x04\x86q\xeeh\x01K\x03\x86q\xefh\x03K\x03\x86q\xf0h\x05K\x02\x86q\xf1h\x07K\x02\x86q\xf2h\tK\x00\x86q\xf3h\x0bK\x01\x86q\xf4h\rK\x01\x86q\xf5h\x0fK\x03\x86q\xf6h\x11K\x02\x86q\xf7h\x13K\x01\x86q\xf8h\x15K\x03\x86q\xf9h\x17K\x04\x86q\xfah\x1bK\x00\x86q\xfbh\x1dK\x03\x86q\xfch\x1fK\x01\x86q\xfdtq\xfe(h\x1bh\x00K\x04\x86q\xffh\x01K\x04\x86r\x00\x01\x00\x00h\x03K\x03\x86r\x01\x01\x00\x00h\x05K\x02\x86r\x02\x01\x00\x00h\x07K\x02\x86r\x03\x01\x00\x00h\tK\x00\x86r\x04\x01\x00\x00h\x0bK\x00\x86r\x05\x01\x00\x00h\rK\x00\x86r\x06\x01\x00\x00h\x0fK\x03\x86r\x07\x01\x00\x00h\x11K\x02\x86r\x08\x01\x00\x00h\x13K\x02\x86r\t\x01\x00\x00h\x15K\x04\x86r\n\x01\x00\x00h\x17K\x04\x86r\x0b\x01\x00\x00h\x19K\x00\x86r\x0c\x01\x00\x00h\x1dK\x03\x86r\r\x01\x00\x00h\x1fK\x02\x86r\x0e\x01\x00\x00tr\x0f\x01\x00\x00(h\x1dh\x00K\x02\x86r\x10\x01\x00\x00h\x01K\x02\x86r\x11\x01\x00\x00h\x03K\x00\x86r\x12\x01\x00\x00h\x05K\x04\x86r\x13\x01\x00\x00h\x07K\x03\x86r\x14\x01\x00\x00h\tK\x03\x86r\x15\x01\x00\x00h\x0bK\x03\x86r\x16\x01\x00\x00h\rK\x03\x86r\x17\x01\x00\x00h\x0fK\x00\x86r\x18\x01\x00\x00h\x11K\x02\x86r\x19\x01\x00\x00h\x13K\x02\x86r\x1a\x01\x00\x00h\x15K\x02\x86r\x1b\x01\x00\x00h\x17K\x02\x86r\x1c\x01\x00\x00h\x19K\x03\x86r\x1d\x01\x00\x00h\x1bK\x03\x86r\x1e\x01\x00\x00h\x1fK\x02\x86r\x1f\x01\x00\x00tr \x01\x00\x00(h\x1fh\x00K\x03\x86r!\x01\x00\x00h\x01K\x03\x86r"\x01\x00\x00h\x03K\x02\x86r#\x01\x00\x00h\x05K\x02\x86r$\x01\x00\x00h\x07K\x01\x86r%\x01\x00\x00h\tK\x01\x86r&\x01\x00\x00h\x0bK\x02\x86r\'\x01\x00\x00h\rK\x02\x86r(\x01\x00\x00h\x0fK\x02\x86r)\x01\x00\x00h\x11K\x01\x86r*\x01\x00\x00h\x13K\x00\x86r+\x01\x00\x00h\x15K\x03\x86r,\x01\x00\x00h\x17K\x03\x86r-\x01\x00\x00h\x19K\x01\x86r.\x01\x00\x00h\x1bK\x02\x86r/\x01\x00\x00h\x1dK\x02\x86r0\x01\x00\x00tr1\x01\x00\x00tr2\x01\x00\x00.'

print(pk2)
b'\x80\x03((X!\x00\x00\x00AA1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0N0P4P4a2a3q\x00X!\x00\x00\x00AA1A3A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0N1P3P4a2a3q\x01K\x01\x86q\x02X!\x00\x00\x00AA2A3A4D2D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2q\x03K\x02\x86q\x04X!\x00\x00\x00AA4A5A5D1D2D2D3H2H4H4N5N5P2P2a2a4q\x05K\x05\x86q\x06X!\x00\x00\x00DA1A3A4A4D2D2D2H1H2H3N4N4P2P2a1a3q\x07K\x04\x86q\x08X!\x00\x00\x00DA2A3A3A4D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0P0a1a3q\tK\x04\x86q\nX!\x00\x00\x00DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3q\x0bK\x04\x86q\x0cX!\x00\x00\x00DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3q\rK\x04\x86q\x0eX!\x00\x00\x00HA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2q\x0fK\x02\x86q\x10X!\x00\x00\x00HA1A2A2A4D2D2D3D3H1H2N1N2P2P2a1a2q\x11K\x02\x86q\x12X!\x00\x00\x00HA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H1H2N3N3P1P2a0a2q\x13K\x03\x86q\x14X!\x00\x00\x00NA0A0A2A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0P3P4a2a3q\x15K\x00\x86q\x16X!\x00\x00\x00NA0A1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0P4P4a2a3q\x17K\x00\x86q\x18X!\x00\x00\x00PA2A3A3A4D0D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0a1a3q\x19K\x04\x86q\x1aX!\x00\x00\x00PA2A3A4A4D0D0D0D2H2H2H3N4N4P0a2a3q\x1bK\x04\x86q\x1cX!\x00\x00\x00aA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a2q\x1dK\x02\x86q\x1eX!\x00\x00\x00aA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H0H1H2N3N3P1P2a2q\x1fK\x03\x86q tq!(h\x01h\x00K\x01\x86q"h\x03K\x03\x86q#h\x05K\x05\x86q$h\x07K\x04\x86q%h\tK\x03\x86q&h\x0bK\x04\x86q\'h\rK\x04\x86q(h\x0fK\x02\x86q)h\x11K\x01\x86q*h\x13K\x03\x86q+h\x15K\x00\x86q,h\x17K\x01\x86q-h\x19K\x03\x86q.h\x1bK\x04\x86q/h\x1dK\x02\x86q0h\x1fK\x03\x86q1tq2(h\x03h\x00K\x02\x86q3h\x01K\x03\x86q4h\x05K\x04\x86q5h\x07K\x03\x86q6h\tK\x03\x86q7h\rK\x02\x86q8h\x0bK\x03\x86q9h\x0fK\x00\x86q:h\x11K\x02\x86q;h\x13K\x02\x86q<h\x15K\x02\x86q=h\x17K\x02\x86q>h\x19K\x03\x86q?h\x1bK\x03\x86q@h\x1dK\x00\x86qAh\x1fK\x02\x86qBtqC(h\x05h\x00K\x05\x86qDh\x01K\x05\x86qEh\x03K\x04\x86qFh\x07K\x01\x86qGh\tK\x02\x86qHh\x0bK\x02\x86qIh\rK\x03\x86qJh\x0fK\x04\x86qKh\x11K\x04\x86qLh\x13K\x02\x86qMh\x15K\x05\x86qNh\x17K\x05\x86qOh\x19K\x02\x86qPh\x1bK\x02\x86qQh\x1dK\x04\x86qRh\x1fK\x02\x86qStqT(h\x07h\x00K\x04\x86qUh\x01K\x04\x86qVh\x03K\x03\x86qWh\x05K\x01\x86qXh\tK\x02\x86qYh\x0bK\x02\x86qZh\rK\x02\x86q[h\x0fK\x03\x86q\\h\x11K\x02\x86q]h\x13K\x01\x86q^h\x15K\x04\x86q_h\x17K\x04\x86q`h\x19K\x02\x86qah\x1bK\x02\x86qbh\x1dK\x03\x86qch\x1fK\x01\x86qdtqe(h\th\x00K\x04\x86qfh\x01K\x03\x86qgh\x03K\x03\x86qhh\x05K\x02\x86qih\x07K\x02\x86qjh\x0bK\x01\x86qkh\rK\x01\x86qlh\x0fK\x03\x86qmh\x11K\x02\x86qnh\x13K\x01\x86qoh\x15K\x03\x86qph\x17K\x04\x86qqh\x19K\x00\x86qrh\x1bK\x00\x86qsh\x1dK\x03\x86qth\x1fK\x01\x86qutqv(h\rh\x00K\x04\x86qwh\x01K\x04\x86qxh\x03K\x02\x86qyh\x05K\x03\x86qzh\x07K\x02\x86q{h\tK\x01\x86q|h\x0bK\x01\x86q}h\x0fK\x03\x86q~h\x11K\x03\x86q\x7fh\x13K\x02\x86q\x80h\x15K\x04\x86q\x81h\x17K\x04\x86q\x82h\x19K\x01\x86q\x83h\x1bK\x00\x86q\x84h\x1dK\x03\x86q\x85h\x1fK\x02\x86q\x86tq\x87(h\x0bh\x00K\x04\x86q\x88h\x01K\x04\x86q\x89h\x03K\x03\x86q\x8ah\x05K\x02\x86q\x8bh\x07K\x02\x86q\x8ch\tK\x01\x86q\x8dh\rK\x01\x86q\x8eh\x0fK\x03\x86q\x8fh\x11K\x03\x86q\x90h\x13K\x02\x86q\x91h\x15K\x04\x86q\x92h\x17K\x04\x86q\x93h\x19K\x01\x86q\x94h\x1bK\x00\x86q\x95h\x1dK\x03\x86q\x96h\x1fK\x02\x86q\x97tq\x98(h\x0fh\x00K\x02\x86q\x99h\x01K\x02\x86q\x9ah\x03K\x00\x86q\x9bh\x05K\x04\x86q\x9ch\x07K\x03\x86q\x9dh\tK\x03\x86q\x9eh\x0bK\x03\x86q\x9fh\rK\x03\x86q\xa0h\x11K\x02\x86q\xa1h\x13K\x02\x86q\xa2h\x15K\x02\x86q\xa3h\x17K\x02\x86q\xa4h\x19K\x03\x86q\xa5h\x1bK\x03\x86q\xa6h\x1dK\x00\x86q\xa7h\x1fK\x02\x86q\xa8tq\xa9(h\x11h\x00K\x02\x86q\xaah\x01K\x01\x86q\xabh\x03K\x02\x86q\xach\x05K\x04\x86q\xadh\x07K\x02\x86q\xaeh\tK\x02\x86q\xafh\x0bK\x03\x86q\xb0h\rK\x03\x86q\xb1h\x0fK\x02\x86q\xb2h\x13K\x01\x86q\xb3h\x15K\x01\x86q\xb4h\x17K\x02\x86q\xb5h\x19K\x02\x86q\xb6h\x1bK\x02\x86q\xb7h\x1dK\x02\x86q\xb8h\x1fK\x01\x86q\xb9tq\xba(h\x13h\x00K\x03\x86q\xbbh\x01K\x03\x86q\xbch\x03K\x02\x86q\xbdh\x05K\x02\x86q\xbeh\x07K\x01\x86q\xbfh\tK\x01\x86q\xc0h\x0bK\x02\x86q\xc1h\rK\x02\x86q\xc2h\x0fK\x02\x86q\xc3h\x11K\x01\x86q\xc4h\x15K\x03\x86q\xc5h\x17K\x03\x86q\xc6h\x19K\x01\x86q\xc7h\x1bK\x02\x86q\xc8h\x1dK\x02\x86q\xc9h\x1fK\x00\x86q\xcatq\xcb(h\x15h\x00K\x00\x86q\xcch\x01K\x00\x86q\xcdh\x03K\x02\x86q\xceh\x05K\x05\x86q\xcfh\x07K\x04\x86q\xd0h\tK\x03\x86q\xd1h\x0bK\x04\x86q\xd2h\rK\x04\x86q\xd3h\x0fK\x02\x86q\xd4h\x11K\x01\x86q\xd5h\x13K\x03\x86q\xd6h\x17K\x00\x86q\xd7h\x19K\x03\x86q\xd8h\x1bK\x04\x86q\xd9h\x1dK\x02\x86q\xdah\x1fK\x03\x86q\xdbtq\xdc(h\x17h\x00K\x00\x86q\xddh\x01K\x01\x86q\xdeh\x03K\x02\x86q\xdfh\x05K\x05\x86q\xe0h\x07K\x04\x86q\xe1h\tK\x04\x86q\xe2h\x0bK\x04\x86q\xe3h\rK\x04\x86q\xe4h\x0fK\x02\x86q\xe5h\x11K\x02\x86q\xe6h\x13K\x03\x86q\xe7h\x15K\x00\x86q\xe8h\x19K\x04\x86q\xe9h\x1bK\x04\x86q\xeah\x1dK\x02\x86q\xebh\x1fK\x03\x86q\xectq\xed(h\x19h\x00K\x04\x86q\xeeh\x01K\x03\x86q\xefh\x03K\x03\x86q\xf0h\x05K\x02\x86q\xf1h\x07K\x02\x86q\xf2h\tK\x00\x86q\xf3h\x0bK\x01\x86q\xf4h\rK\x01\x86q\xf5h\x0fK\x03\x86q\xf6h\x11K\x02\x86q\xf7h\x13K\x01\x86q\xf8h\x15K\x03\x86q\xf9h\x17K\x04\x86q\xfah\x1bK\x00\x86q\xfbh\x1dK\x03\x86q\xfch\x1fK\x01\x86q\xfdtq\xfe(h\x1bh\x00K\x04\x86q\xffh\x01K\x04\x86r\x00\x01\x00\x00h\x03K\x03\x86r\x01\x01\x00\x00h\x05K\x02\x86r\x02\x01\x00\x00h\x07K\x02\x86r\x03\x01\x00\x00h\tK\x00\x86r\x04\x01\x00\x00h\x0bK\x00\x86r\x05\x01\x00\x00h\rK\x00\x86r\x06\x01\x00\x00h\x0fK\x03\x86r\x07\x01\x00\x00h\x11K\x02\x86r\x08\x01\x00\x00h\x13K\x02\x86r\t\x01\x00\x00h\x15K\x04\x86r\n\x01\x00\x00h\x17K\x04\x86r\x0b\x01\x00\x00h\x19K\x00\x86r\x0c\x01\x00\x00h\x1dK\x03\x86r\r\x01\x00\x00h\x1fK\x02\x86r\x0e\x01\x00\x00tr\x0f\x01\x00\x00(h\x1dh\x00K\x02\x86r\x10\x01\x00\x00h\x01K\x02\x86r\x11\x01\x00\x00h\x03K\x00\x86r\x12\x01\x00\x00h\x05K\x04\x86r\x13\x01\x00\x00h\x07K\x03\x86r\x14\x01\x00\x00h\tK\x03\x86r\x15\x01\x00\x00h\x0bK\x03\x86r\x16\x01\x00\x00h\rK\x03\x86r\x17\x01\x00\x00h\x0fK\x00\x86r\x18\x01\x00\x00h\x11K\x02\x86r\x19\x01\x00\x00h\x13K\x02\x86r\x1a\x01\x00\x00h\x15K\x02\x86r\x1b\x01\x00\x00h\x17K\x02\x86r\x1c\x01\x00\x00h\x19K\x03\x86r\x1d\x01\x00\x00h\x1bK\x03\x86r\x1e\x01\x00\x00h\x1fK\x02\x86r\x1f\x01\x00\x00tr \x01\x00\x00(h\x1fh\x00K\x03\x86r!\x01\x00\x00h\x01K\x03\x86r"\x01\x00\x00h\x03K\x02\x86r#\x01\x00\x00h\x05K\x02\x86r$\x01\x00\x00h\x07K\x01\x86r%\x01\x00\x00h\tK\x01\x86r&\x01\x00\x00h\x0bK\x02\x86r\'\x01\x00\x00h\rK\x02\x86r(\x01\x00\x00h\x0fK\x02\x86r)\x01\x00\x00h\x11K\x01\x86r*\x01\x00\x00h\x13K\x00\x86r+\x01\x00\x00h\x15K\x03\x86r,\x01\x00\x00h\x17K\x03\x86r-\x01\x00\x00h\x19K\x01\x86r.\x01\x00\x00h\x1bK\x02\x86r/\x01\x00\x00h\x1dK\x02\x86r0\x01\x00\x00tr1\x01\x00\x00tr2\x01\x00\x00.'

for n, (i, j) in enumerate(zip(pk1, pk2)):
    if i != j:
        print(n, i, j)

924 11 13
931 13 11
1042 13 11
1049 11 13
1359 11 13
1403 13 11
1477 13 11
1521 11 13
```

If I unpickle them back and compare results they are identical:

```
upk1 = pickle.loads(pk1)
upk2 = pickle.loads(pk2)

print(upk1 == upk2)
True
```

So the questions are what is caused this issue and how to avoid it? Are there some metadata pickled?

Hmm, I found one related question [Python pickle not one-to-one: different pickles give same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271479/python-pickle-not-one-to-one-different-pickles-give-same-object). So pickle can return different results for the identical objects? And thus it is inappropriate for hash calculation? Since I planned to calculate md5 hashes based on pickled representation.

UPDATE: text representation of `s1` and `s2`:

```
(('AA1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0N0P4P4a2a3',
  ('AA1A3A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0N1P3P4a2a3', 1),
  ('AA2A3A4D2D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2', 2),
  ('AA4A5A5D1D2D2D3H2H4H4N5N5P2P2a2a4', 5),
  ('DA1A3A4A4D2D2D2H1H2H3N4N4P2P2a1a3', 4),
  ('DA2A3A3A4D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0P0a1a3', 4),
  ('DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3', 4),
  ('DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3', 4),
  ('HA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2', 2),
  ('HA1A2A2A4D2D2D3D3H1H2N1N2P2P2a1a2', 2),
  ('HA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H1H2N3N3P1P2a0a2', 3),
  ('NA0A0A2A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0P3P4a2a3', 0),
  ('NA0A1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0P4P4a2a3', 0),
  ('PA2A3A3A4D0D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0a1a3', 4),
  ('PA2A3A4A4D0D0D0D2H2H2H3N4N4P0a2a3', 4),
  ('aA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a2', 2),
  ('aA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H0H1H2N3N3P1P2a2', 3)),
 ('AA1A3A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0N1P3P4a2a3',
  ('AA1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0N0P4P4a2a3', 1),
  ('AA2A3A4D2D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2', 3),
  ('AA4A5A5D1D2D2D3H2H4H4N5N5P2P2a2a4', 5),
  ('DA1A3A4A4D2D2D2H1H2H3N4N4P2P2a1a3', 4),
  ('DA2A3A3A4D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0P0a1a3', 3),
  ('DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3', 4),
  ('DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3', 4),
  ('HA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2', 2),
  ('HA1A2A2A4D2D2D3D3H1H2N1N2P2P2a1a2', 1),
  ('HA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H1H2N3N3P1P2a0a2', 3),
  ('NA0A0A2A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0P3P4a2a3', 0),
  ('NA0A1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0P4P4a2a3', 1),
  ('PA2A3A3A4D0D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0a1a3', 3),
  ('PA2A3A4A4D0D0D0D2H2H2H3N4N4P0a2a3', 4),
  ('aA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a2', 2),
  ('aA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H0H1H2N3N3P1P2a2', 3)),
 ('AA2A3A4D2D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2',
  ('AA1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0N0P4P4a2a3', 2),
  ('AA1A3A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0N1P3P4a2a3', 3),
  ('AA4A5A5D1D2D2D3H2H4H4N5N5P2P2a2a4', 4),
  ('DA1A3A4A4D2D2D2H1H2H3N4N4P2P2a1a3', 3),
  ('DA2A3A3A4D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0P0a1a3', 3),
  ('DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3', 2),
  ('DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3', 3),
  ('HA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2', 0),
  ('HA1A2A2A4D2D2D3D3H1H2N1N2P2P2a1a2', 2),
  ('HA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H1H2N3N3P1P2a0a2', 2),
  ('NA0A0A2A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0P3P4a2a3', 2),
  ('NA0A1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0P4P4a2a3', 2),
  ('PA2A3A3A4D0D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0a1a3', 3),
  ('PA2A3A4A4D0D0D0D2H2H2H3N4N4P0a2a3', 3),
  ('aA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a2', 0),
  ('aA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H0H1H2N3N3P1P2a2', 2)),
 ('AA4A5A5D1D2D2D3H2H4H4N5N5P2P2a2a4',
  ('AA1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0N0P4P4a2a3', 5),
  ('AA1A3A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0N1P3P4a2a3', 5),
  ('AA2A3A4D2D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2', 4),
  ('DA1A3A4A4D2D2D2H1H2H3N4N4P2P2a1a3', 1),
  ('DA2A3A3A4D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0P0a1a3', 2),
  ('DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3', 2),
  ('DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3', 3),
  ('HA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2', 4),
  ('HA1A2A2A4D2D2D3D3H1H2N1N2P2P2a1a2', 4),
  ('HA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H1H2N3N3P1P2a0a2', 2),
  ('NA0A0A2A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0P3P4a2a3', 5),
  ('NA0A1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0P4P4a2a3', 5),
  ('PA2A3A3A4D0D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0a1a3', 2),
  ('PA2A3A4A4D0D0D0D2H2H2H3N4N4P0a2a3', 2),
  ('aA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a2', 4),
  ('aA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H0H1H2N3N3P1P2a2', 2)),
 ('DA1A3A4A4D2D2D2H1H2H3N4N4P2P2a1a3',
  ('AA1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0N0P4P4a2a3', 4),
  ('AA1A3A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0N1P3P4a2a3', 4),
  ('AA2A3A4D2D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2', 3),
  ('AA4A5A5D1D2D2D3H2H4H4N5N5P2P2a2a4', 1),
  ('DA2A3A3A4D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0P0a1a3', 2),
  ('DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3', 2),
  ('DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3', 2),
  ('HA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2', 3),
  ('HA1A2A2A4D2D2D3D3H1H2N1N2P2P2a1a2', 2),
  ('HA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H1H2N3N3P1P2a0a2', 1),
  ('NA0A0A2A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0P3P4a2a3', 4),
  ('NA0A1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0P4P4a2a3', 4),
  ('PA2A3A3A4D0D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0a1a3', 2),
  ('PA2A3A4A4D0D0D0D2H2H2H3N4N4P0a2a3', 2),
  ('aA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a2', 3),
  ('aA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H0H1H2N3N3P1P2a2', 1)),
 ('DA2A3A3A4D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0P0a1a3',
  ('AA1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0N0P4P4a2a3', 4),
  ('AA1A3A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0N1P3P4a2a3', 3),
  ('AA2A3A4D2D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2', 3),
  ('AA4A5A5D1D2D2D3H2H4H4N5N5P2P2a2a4', 2),
  ('DA1A3A4A4D2D2D2H1H2H3N4N4P2P2a1a3', 2),
  ('DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3', 1),
  ('DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3', 1),
  ('HA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2', 3),
  ('HA1A2A2A4D2D2D3D3H1H2N1N2P2P2a1a2', 2),
  ('HA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H1H2N3N3P1P2a0a2', 1),
  ('NA0A0A2A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0P3P4a2a3', 3),
  ('NA0A1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0P4P4a2a3', 4),
  ('PA2A3A3A4D0D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0a1a3', 0),
  ('PA2A3A4A4D0D0D0D2H2H2H3N4N4P0a2a3', 0),
  ('aA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a2', 3),
  ('aA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H0H1H2N3N3P1P2a2', 1)),
 ('DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3',
  ('AA1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0N0P4P4a2a3', 4),
  ('AA1A3A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0N1P3P4a2a3', 4),
  ('AA2A3A4D2D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2', 2),
  ('AA4A5A5D1D2D2D3H2H4H4N5N5P2P2a2a4', 3),
  ('DA1A3A4A4D2D2D2H1H2H3N4N4P2P2a1a3', 2),
  ('DA2A3A3A4D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0P0a1a3', 1),
  ('DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3', 1),
  ('HA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2', 3),
  ('HA1A2A2A4D2D2D3D3H1H2N1N2P2P2a1a2', 3),
  ('HA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H1H2N3N3P1P2a0a2', 2),
  ('NA0A0A2A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0P3P4a2a3', 4),
  ('NA0A1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0P4P4a2a3', 4),
  ('PA2A3A3A4D0D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0a1a3', 1),
  ('PA2A3A4A4D0D0D0D2H2H2H3N4N4P0a2a3', 0),
  ('aA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a2', 3),
  ('aA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H0H1H2N3N3P1P2a2', 2)),
 ('DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3',
  ('AA1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0N0P4P4a2a3', 4),
  ('AA1A3A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0N1P3P4a2a3', 4),
  ('AA2A3A4D2D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2', 3),
  ('AA4A5A5D1D2D2D3H2H4H4N5N5P2P2a2a4', 2),
  ('DA1A3A4A4D2D2D2H1H2H3N4N4P2P2a1a3', 2),
  ('DA2A3A3A4D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0P0a1a3', 1),
  ('DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3', 1),
  ('HA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2', 3),
  ('HA1A2A2A4D2D2D3D3H1H2N1N2P2P2a1a2', 3),
  ('HA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H1H2N3N3P1P2a0a2', 2),
  ('NA0A0A2A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0P3P4a2a3', 4),
  ('NA0A1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0P4P4a2a3', 4),
  ('PA2A3A3A4D0D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0a1a3', 1),
  ('PA2A3A4A4D0D0D0D2H2H2H3N4N4P0a2a3', 0),
  ('aA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a2', 3),
  ('aA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H0H1H2N3N3P1P2a2', 2)),
 ('HA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2',
  ('AA1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0N0P4P4a2a3', 2),
  ('AA1A3A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0N1P3P4a2a3', 2),
  ('AA2A3A4D2D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2', 0),
  ('AA4A5A5D1D2D2D3H2H4H4N5N5P2P2a2a4', 4),
  ('DA1A3A4A4D2D2D2H1H2H3N4N4P2P2a1a3', 3),
  ('DA2A3A3A4D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0P0a1a3', 3),
  ('DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3', 3),
  ('DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3', 3),
  ('HA1A2A2A4D2D2D3D3H1H2N1N2P2P2a1a2', 2),
  ('HA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H1H2N3N3P1P2a0a2', 2),
  ('NA0A0A2A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0P3P4a2a3', 2),
  ('NA0A1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0P4P4a2a3', 2),
  ('PA2A3A3A4D0D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0a1a3', 3),
  ('PA2A3A4A4D0D0D0D2H2H2H3N4N4P0a2a3', 3),
  ('aA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a2', 0),
  ('aA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H0H1H2N3N3P1P2a2', 2)),
 ('HA1A2A2A4D2D2D3D3H1H2N1N2P2P2a1a2',
  ('AA1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0N0P4P4a2a3', 2),
  ('AA1A3A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0N1P3P4a2a3', 1),
  ('AA2A3A4D2D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2', 2),
  ('AA4A5A5D1D2D2D3H2H4H4N5N5P2P2a2a4', 4),
  ('DA1A3A4A4D2D2D2H1H2H3N4N4P2P2a1a3', 2),
  ('DA2A3A3A4D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0P0a1a3', 2),
  ('DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3', 3),
  ('DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3', 3),
  ('HA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2', 2),
  ('HA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H1H2N3N3P1P2a0a2', 1),
  ('NA0A0A2A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0P3P4a2a3', 1),
  ('NA0A1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0P4P4a2a3', 2),
  ('PA2A3A3A4D0D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0a1a3', 2),
  ('PA2A3A4A4D0D0D0D2H2H2H3N4N4P0a2a3', 2),
  ('aA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a2', 2),
  ('aA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H0H1H2N3N3P1P2a2', 1)),
 ('HA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H1H2N3N3P1P2a0a2',
  ('AA1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0N0P4P4a2a3', 3),
  ('AA1A3A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0N1P3P4a2a3', 3),
  ('AA2A3A4D2D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2', 2),
  ('AA4A5A5D1D2D2D3H2H4H4N5N5P2P2a2a4', 2),
  ('DA1A3A4A4D2D2D2H1H2H3N4N4P2P2a1a3', 1),
  ('DA2A3A3A4D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0P0a1a3', 1),
  ('DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3', 2),
  ('DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3', 2),
  ('HA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2', 2),
  ('HA1A2A2A4D2D2D3D3H1H2N1N2P2P2a1a2', 1),
  ('NA0A0A2A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0P3P4a2a3', 3),
  ('NA0A1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0P4P4a2a3', 3),
  ('PA2A3A3A4D0D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0a1a3', 1),
  ('PA2A3A4A4D0D0D0D2H2H2H3N4N4P0a2a3', 2),
  ('aA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a2', 2),
  ('aA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H0H1H2N3N3P1P2a2', 0)),
 ('NA0A0A2A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0P3P4a2a3',
  ('AA1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0N0P4P4a2a3', 0),
  ('AA1A3A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0N1P3P4a2a3', 0),
  ('AA2A3A4D2D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2', 2),
  ('AA4A5A5D1D2D2D3H2H4H4N5N5P2P2a2a4', 5),
  ('DA1A3A4A4D2D2D2H1H2H3N4N4P2P2a1a3', 4),
  ('DA2A3A3A4D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0P0a1a3', 3),
  ('DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3', 4),
  ('DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3', 4),
  ('HA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2', 2),
  ('HA1A2A2A4D2D2D3D3H1H2N1N2P2P2a1a2', 1),
  ('HA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H1H2N3N3P1P2a0a2', 3),
  ('NA0A1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0P4P4a2a3', 0),
  ('PA2A3A3A4D0D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0a1a3', 3),
  ('PA2A3A4A4D0D0D0D2H2H2H3N4N4P0a2a3', 4),
  ('aA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a2', 2),
  ('aA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H0H1H2N3N3P1P2a2', 3)),
 ('NA0A1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0P4P4a2a3',
  ('AA1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0N0P4P4a2a3', 0),
  ('AA1A3A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0N1P3P4a2a3', 1),
  ('AA2A3A4D2D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2', 2),
  ('AA4A5A5D1D2D2D3H2H4H4N5N5P2P2a2a4', 5),
  ('DA1A3A4A4D2D2D2H1H2H3N4N4P2P2a1a3', 4),
  ('DA2A3A3A4D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0P0a1a3', 4),
  ('DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3', 4),
  ('DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3', 4),
  ('HA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2', 2),
  ('HA1A2A2A4D2D2D3D3H1H2N1N2P2P2a1a2', 2),
  ('HA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H1H2N3N3P1P2a0a2', 3),
  ('NA0A0A2A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0P3P4a2a3', 0),
  ('PA2A3A3A4D0D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0a1a3', 4),
  ('PA2A3A4A4D0D0D0D2H2H2H3N4N4P0a2a3', 4),
  ('aA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a2', 2),
  ('aA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H0H1H2N3N3P1P2a2', 3)),
 ('PA2A3A3A4D0D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0a1a3',
  ('AA1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0N0P4P4a2a3', 4),
  ('AA1A3A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0N1P3P4a2a3', 3),
  ('AA2A3A4D2D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2', 3),
  ('AA4A5A5D1D2D2D3H2H4H4N5N5P2P2a2a4', 2),
  ('DA1A3A4A4D2D2D2H1H2H3N4N4P2P2a1a3', 2),
  ('DA2A3A3A4D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0P0a1a3', 0),
  ('DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3', 1),
  ('DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3', 1),
  ('HA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2', 3),
  ('HA1A2A2A4D2D2D3D3H1H2N1N2P2P2a1a2', 2),
  ('HA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H1H2N3N3P1P2a0a2', 1),
  ('NA0A0A2A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0P3P4a2a3', 3),
  ('NA0A1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0P4P4a2a3', 4),
  ('PA2A3A4A4D0D0D0D2H2H2H3N4N4P0a2a3', 0),
  ('aA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a2', 3),
  ('aA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H0H1H2N3N3P1P2a2', 1)),
 ('PA2A3A4A4D0D0D0D2H2H2H3N4N4P0a2a3',
  ('AA1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0N0P4P4a2a3', 4),
  ('AA1A3A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0N1P3P4a2a3', 4),
  ('AA2A3A4D2D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2', 3),
  ('AA4A5A5D1D2D2D3H2H4H4N5N5P2P2a2a4', 2),
  ('DA1A3A4A4D2D2D2H1H2H3N4N4P2P2a1a3', 2),
  ('DA2A3A3A4D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0P0a1a3', 0),
  ('DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3', 0),
  ('DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3', 0),
  ('HA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2', 3),
  ('HA1A2A2A4D2D2D3D3H1H2N1N2P2P2a1a2', 2),
  ('HA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H1H2N3N3P1P2a0a2', 2),
  ('NA0A0A2A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0P3P4a2a3', 4),
  ('NA0A1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0P4P4a2a3', 4),
  ('PA2A3A3A4D0D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0a1a3', 0),
  ('aA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a2', 3),
  ('aA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H0H1H2N3N3P1P2a2', 2)),
 ('aA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a2',
  ('AA1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0N0P4P4a2a3', 2),
  ('AA1A3A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0N1P3P4a2a3', 2),
  ('AA2A3A4D2D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2', 0),
  ('AA4A5A5D1D2D2D3H2H4H4N5N5P2P2a2a4', 4),
  ('DA1A3A4A4D2D2D2H1H2H3N4N4P2P2a1a3', 3),
  ('DA2A3A3A4D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0P0a1a3', 3),
  ('DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3', 3),
  ('DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3', 3),
  ('HA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2', 0),
  ('HA1A2A2A4D2D2D3D3H1H2N1N2P2P2a1a2', 2),
  ('HA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H1H2N3N3P1P2a0a2', 2),
  ('NA0A0A2A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0P3P4a2a3', 2),
  ('NA0A1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0P4P4a2a3', 2),
  ('PA2A3A3A4D0D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0a1a3', 3),
  ('PA2A3A4A4D0D0D0D2H2H2H3N4N4P0a2a3', 3),
  ('aA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H0H1H2N3N3P1P2a2', 2)),
 ('aA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H0H1H2N3N3P1P2a2',
  ('AA1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0N0P4P4a2a3', 3),
  ('AA1A3A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0N1P3P4a2a3', 3),
  ('AA2A3A4D2D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2', 2),
  ('AA4A5A5D1D2D2D3H2H4H4N5N5P2P2a2a4', 2),
  ('DA1A3A4A4D2D2D2H1H2H3N4N4P2P2a1a3', 1),
  ('DA2A3A3A4D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0P0a1a3', 1),
  ('DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3', 2),
  ('DA2A3A4A4D1D1D2H2H3H3N4N4P0P1a2a3', 2),
  ('HA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H2H2N2N2P3P3a0a2', 2),
  ('HA1A2A2A4D2D2D3D3H1H2N1N2P2P2a1a2', 1),
  ('HA2A2A3A3D1D1D2D2H1H2N3N3P1P2a0a2', 0),
  ('NA0A0A2A5D3D4D4D4H1H2H3N0P3P4a2a3', 3),
  ('NA0A1A2A5D4D4D4D4H2H2H3N0P4P4a2a3', 3),
  ('PA2A3A3A4D0D1D1D2H1H2H3N3N4P0a1a3', 1),
  ('PA2A3A4A4D0D0D0D2H2H2H3N4N4P0a2a3', 2),
  ('aA0A2A2A4D3D3D3D3H0H2H2N2N2P3P3a2', 2)))
```

Comment: What's the content of the tuples?  `s1` and `s2` are considered equal if each of their elements are also equal.  If the types of those elements override the equality operator (by defining `__eq__`), then two different objects with different internal state (as seen by `pickle`) can be considered equal.

Comment: What are you using the hashes for? Do you want them, for example, to distinguish between `1` and `1.0`? (As a more tangential thing, where are the objects you're pickling going to be coming from?)

Comment: @WillVousden, I added text representation of `s1` and `s2` (they are identical). They are tuple of tuples of strings and integers.`s1` and `s2` are hashable and `hash` works perfectly, However it is not suitable for storing and duplicates finding, since it has a high chance of collisions.

Comment: This problem happened to me with json.dumps. The strings are different but when the files are unpickled, are the same

Comment: @mwchase, I generate these object `s1` and `s2` by myself using two different procedures. Almost all of them were identical according to md5 hashes except several cases. However I discovered that in reality objects with different md5 hashes are identical but their pickled versions are different.

Comment: If you want to compute the hash you can always just do `hash(repr(s1))`. `repr` will return you the same representation if the tuples are equal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `pickle` [preserves identity relationships between subobjects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#comparison-with-marshal) (this is for efficiency and to handle recursive objects):

```
a1 = "a" * 30
a2 = "a" * 30
s1 = (a1, a2, a1)
s2 = (a1, a2, a2)
print(pickle.dumps(s1) == pickle.dumps(s2))
False
```

Here, `a1` and `a2` are equal but are different objects (they have a different `id`; see [When does python choose to intern a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622472/when-does-python-choose-to-intern-a-string?lq=1)); `s1` and `s2` are again equal but in `s1` the third element is the *same object* as the **first** element, while in `s2` the third element is the same object as the **second** element.

We can see this by disassembling the pickles:

```
>>> pickletools.dis(pickle.dumps(s1))
    0: \x80 PROTO      3
    2: X    BINUNICODE 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
   37: q    BINPUT     0
   39: X    BINUNICODE 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
   74: q    BINPUT     1
   76: h    BINGET     0  # <=== watch this line *********************
   78: \x87 TUPLE3
   79: q    BINPUT     2
   81: .    STOP
highest protocol among opcodes = 2

>>> pickletools.dis(pickle.dumps(s2))
    0: \x80 PROTO      3
    2: X    BINUNICODE 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
   37: q    BINPUT     0
   39: X    BINUNICODE 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
   74: q    BINPUT     1
   76: h    BINGET     1  # <=== this is different *********************
   78: \x87 TUPLE3
   79: q    BINPUT     2
   81: .    STOP
highest protocol among opcodes = 2
```

A quick (if inefficient) workaround could be to break the object identities by using `ast.literal_eval` to recreate the tuples from their `repr`:

```
>>> print(pickle.dumps(ast.literal_eval(repr(s1))) == pickle.dumps(ast.literal_eval(repr(s2))))
True
```

Comment: Great explanation and interesting nitty-gritty :)

Comment: But what is an advantage in usage of `ast.literal_eval`? It works with `repr` only.

Comment: @DrDom `ast.literal_eval` reverses `repr` for plain data objects, so it gives  you back tuple objects that you could continue to work with. If you're only using `pickle` for the hash then using `repr` directly would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried with marshal module (https://docs.python.org/2/library/marshal.html#module-marshal), and works. Look the example

```
import marshal
# code ...
string1 = marshal.dumps(sp1)
```

Comment: This comment is related to differences in `pickle` and `cPickle`. I used only `pickle` module.

Comment: Yes, you have reason, I removed the section. I tested marshal module and works!, look at the edit.

Comment: Yes, it works, looks that `marshar` works more consistently then `pickle` for serialization. However, I expect that it is not recommended to use it since maintainers may change this module in incompartible way (according to the given link description).