# pickling a deserialized object produces different binary (vs original)

Tags: python, numpy, pickle

I came across some weird behavior where pickle was producing different serialized output for the same input. It is somehow triggered when serializing a deserialized pickled object (as could happen if the object was retrieved from `mp.Queue`). It also only happens when the list has more than one element (not sure why). Can someone explain what is going on here? I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37748001/identical-tuples-give-different-pickles/37748905#37748905) but it doesn't seem to be the same situation, as `a`,`b`,`c` all have different ids.

Code to reproduce below. I'm using Python 3.6.3 from Anaconda.

```
import pickle
import numpy as np

def f():
    return np.array([1,2,3])

a = f()
b = f()
c = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(f()))

print(id(a), id(b), id(c)) # 4464565184 4464565504 4466959424

print('[a]==[b]', pickle.dumps([a]) == pickle.dumps([b])) # True
print('[a]==[c]', pickle.dumps([a]) == pickle.dumps([c])) # True
print('[b]==[c]', pickle.dumps([b]) == pickle.dumps([c])) # True
print('[a,b]==[a,c]', pickle.dumps([a,b]) == pickle.dumps([a,c])) # False
print('a.tolist()==c.tolist()', a.tolist()==c.tolist()) # True
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be problem specific to numpy as without it, pickle works just fine 
in python 3.6.6:

```
import pickle

def f():
    return [1,2,3]

a = f()
b = f()
c = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(f()))

print(id(a), id(b), id(c)) # 1900503702728 1900503865288 1900503976328

print('[a]==[b]', pickle.dumps([a]) == pickle.dumps([b])) # True
print('[a]==[c]', pickle.dumps([a]) == pickle.dumps([c])) # True
print('[b]==[c]', pickle.dumps([b]) == pickle.dumps([c])) # True
print('[a,b]==[a,c]', pickle.dumps([a,b]) == pickle.dumps([a,c])) # True
```

[numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) [python](/questions/tagged/python) [pickle](/questions/tagged/pickle) [nondeterministic](/questions/tagged/nondeterministic) [python3](/questions/tagged/python3)